# how add date to TimeSeries in LineGraph achartengine

Tags: android, sqlite, time-series, achartengine, linegraph

I use AchartEngine to create a LineGraph.

I have the data from the database in the format:

```
dd-mm-yyyy count
```

for example:

```
01-05-2013 3
01-08-2013 7
01-11-2013 4
01-12-2013 15
...
```

code fragment

```
... 
    int values = new Date[myCursor.getCount()];
    Date[] dat = new Date[myCursor.getCount()];
    SimpleDateFormat dfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    do{
       try {
             dat[kk]=dfIn.parse(myCursor.getString(0));
             values[kk]=myCursor.getInt(1);
       } 
       catch (ParseException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
        kk++;

    }
    while(myCursor.moveToNext());
...

TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1"); 
    for( int i = 0; i < dat.length; i++)
    {
        series.add(datki[i], values[i]);
    }
```

I have a questions:

Dates and values ​​I hold in separate tables.
How can I add to TimeSeries this data ???
Is it possible to add the date in the format mm-yyyy ???

Please help

Comment: What are you using TimeChart or XYChart?

Comment: mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, mRenderer); But if there is another way is very willing it will use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using chartfactory :

```
 intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(this, getDateDemoDataset(), getDemoRenderer(), "MM-yyyy");
```

If using timechart:

```
 TimeChart chart = new TimeChart(dataset, renderer);
    chart.setDateFormat("MM-yyyy");
```